# call setter in function of same class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a TypeError this._arg is not a function from this code bellow

```
class temp {
    constructor( _argx) {
        this._arg( _argx);
        console.log( this.arg);
    }
    get _arg() { return this.arg; }
    set _arg( value) { this.arg= value; }
}
let v= new temp( { 'foo': 'bar'});
```

It's not possible to call setter inside the class ?

Thanks

Comment: For a setter shouldn't you use 'this._arg = _argx' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only call a getter / setter pair if the getter returns a function, which then gets executed by the call. To call the setter, just *set* (`=`) it.

And by convention, you "hide" the background field with `_`, not the setter itself:

```
class temp {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
    console.log(this.arg);
  }
  get arg() { return this._arg; }
  set arg(value) { this._arg = value; }
}
```